# How to create a system to access a page after payment has been made in https://www.realcredit.com/?

Tags: php, payment-gateway, payment, payment-processing

I want to create a credit card payment processing section in https://www.realcredit.com/ for my site. The users are allowed to access a page after payment has been made. What are all the steps needed to create a system like this. If anyone worked on credit card processing in Realcredit for a PHP site, guide me to implement the credit card processing section.

Answer (score 0):

First you should specify if that payment is for a one time service or some sort of longer subscription/license.

If it's just a one time payment you might want to create a system where one can access the page using a single-use token. (You visit the page with an appended security token on the url and your session gets validated and the token invalidated.)

Then implement the payment system according to the API of realcredit.com and once the payment has cleared send a mail to the customer (or if clearance is instant display a page) containing a link with such a one-time token.

If you want to implement something like a license system then you might want to first implement a user-login for your page or a user database. Then once the payment has cleared set a flag on said user-record in your database allowing access to the page you want to protect.

Comment: could you suggest few websites using realcredit payment system?

Comment: Maybe you should contact realcredit for a sample implementation. I don't think realcredit will disclose their customerbase.

Comment: If you need an answer more specific for realcredit.com's payment system instead of a generic implementation idea you should provide some code of what you have tried so far and where your problem is with that solution. e.g. if you're running into errors.